# How to randomly pick a string from multiple finals strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, random, final

As the question says, I've got multiple finals strings in a final class like this:

```
public final class MyStrings {

    public static final String stringOne = "this is string one";
    public static final String stringTwo = "this is string two";
    public static final String stringThree = "this is string three";
    public static final String stringFour = "this is string four";
    public static final String stringFive = "this is string five";

}
```

I know it could be easier to put them in a list or an array, but I would like to avoid runtime filling of those structures. Is it possible? What is the simplest way to choose randomly a string from that class? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not wish to store these as an array?  Seems the obvious and simplest solution.  What do you mean by _runtime filling_?

Comment: runtime filling: myList.add("myString") in a list

Comment: Then why is an array not appropriate for you?

Comment: As other posters have commented, you are going to **have** to put those constants into an array or collection of some sort in order to randomly select one (other than using a horrible big switch statement).  Still not sure why this is a problem?

Comment: I think the main problem is that you think your current method is better than an array.

Comment: I don't understand why there's a downvote, thank you all anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `String`s seem very related, since you have a use case that needs to randomly choose one among them. Therefore, they should probably be gathered in an array anyway (on a semantic point of view).

There won't be more *"runtime filling"* than with your current multiple fields:

```
public final class MyStrings {

    public static final String[] strings = {
        "this is string one",
        "this is string two",
        "this is string three",
        "this is string four",
        "this is string five"
    };
}
```

Then you can pick one `String` randomly this way:

```
Random random = new Random();
String randomString = strings[random.nextInt(strings.length)]);
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, and probably there's no better way of doing it, right?

Comment: Why would something else be better? It's exactly equivalent as having several different fields. Moreover, these fields actually *should* be gathered if they are related.

Comment: Thank you Joffrey! I thaught that there was something easier (and you're right, it's equivalent as having different fields)

Comment: Nope, I don't think there is something allowing you to randomly choose among different fields, unless you use reflection, which is terribly dirty ^^

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] mystring = {
    "this is string one",
    "this is string two",
    "this is string three",
    "this is string four",
    "this is string five"
};

int idx = new Random().nextInt(mystring.length);
String random = (mystring [idx]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Put those strings into final array and generate a random number from 0 to `array.length-1`

Comment: So, are you suggesting something like this? 

public static final String[] myStrings = {
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
 };

Comment: @user432 OP asked for a way without filling the array at runtime, there's nothing specifically against arrays and lists

Comment: Yeah, final array is not about runtime filling. So it appears to be an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't worry about the performance cost of filling an array with those strings, as it's by far the most logical way of doing this!

Load each string into an array and generate a random number from 0 (array indexes start at 0, be careful!) to the end of the array - 1 (because the array starts at 0, you have to minus 1 from the length of the array). And then use the random number as an index for choosing a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use an enum:

```
public enum MyStrings {
    ONE("This is string one"),
    ETCETERA("Other strings");

    private final String label;

    private MyStrings(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

then

```
String randomLabel = MyStrings.values()[random.nextInt(MyStrings.values().length].label;
```

This has 2 advantages:

1. it allows you to delay turning the enum values into `String`s (possibly making type signatures in the rest of the code more helpful).
2. it prevents you from being able to replace the array values with other strings.

Performance caveat: this approach does have the slight performance impact of creating a new (short) array in memory every time `MyStrings.values()` is called. That is unlikely to have any measurable impact. In the unlikely case that you do measure that this is a bottleneck (you'd probably want to use a custom random function, then, too), you can either optimize this away or choose a different structure after all.

Comment: It might be kinda overkill if the OP doesn't need the extra functionality provided by an enum (and he doesn't seem to need it).

Comment: That's impossible to tell from his question. I like this approach as it allows you to delay turning the enum values into `String`s (possibly making type signatures in the rest of the code more helpful). Also it prevents you from being able to replace the array values with other strings.

Comment: *it allows you to delay turning the enum values into Strings* True, but it also creates a new array each time you use the `values()` method (This is actually why you last argument is true too). Anyway, you deserve a +1 for the suggestion and the arguments behind it (you should probably edit your answer to add those arguments btw).

Comment: That's correct. You could optimize that away of course, but I doubt creating those 5-element arrays is likely to be your applications' performance bottleneck.

Comment: Storing the array to prevent its recreation would make your "not overwritable" argument false, and actually would lead to my solution. Not storing it and using `values()` in a large number of random accesses would not be very clean, because it would make the GC go crazy. However, I grant you that the performance would not be a problem at all if those random accesses are limited ;)

Comment: I guess you could work around that by having something like a `getRandomElement` method and keeping the stored array local to that, but yeah, that's kind of defeating the purpose :).

Comment: Very true indeed ^^ Thanks for updating your answer by the way.

Answer (score -3):

use reflection api to get all `public static final String` fields from MyStrings.class into an array, called strings

then randomly generate an integer n from 0 to numStrings - 1,

random string is strings[n]

Comment: What drove you to decide that reflection would be the best solution here?

Comment: of cause I known that, but I guess, the MyStrings class is a class from other place, eg. a jar library. And he doesn't know the names of the Strings, or there are too many strings.

Comment: Also, how would the user distinguish between the strings he wants to pick from, and other static final strings?

Comment: If the third party jar file upgraded, he doesn't know.